# How to detect caller in haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am setting a property, I need to know who is setting the property value? is this possible in haxe 3?

Also, can I know who is calling a function from inside the function itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [PosInfos](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/PosInfos.html).  You use it like so:

```
public static function add(a:Int, b:Int, ?pos:PosInfos) {
    trace( 'Called from ${pos.className}');
    trace( 'Called from ${pos.methodName}');
    trace( 'Called from ${pos.fileName}');
    trace( 'Called from ${pos.lineNumber}');
    return a+b;
}

add( 1, 1 ); // "pos" will automatically be filled in by compiler
```